# SmartEditService.isLaunchedInSmartEdit() is always returns null

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have Spartacus storefront app.

Spartacus version is 3.2.2.

I have the requirement to check if the page is loaded in smart edit or not.

For that I tried to use `this.smartEditService.isLaunchedInSmartEdit()` but it always returns null value.

Please help me to find solution.

Below is my sample service code.

```
import { Product, ProductService, RoutingService, CmsService, SmartEditService } from '@spartacus/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CurrentProductService {

  constructor(
    private smartEditService: SmartEditService
  ) {

  }

  getProduct(): Observable<Product> {
  
    if (this.smartEditService && this.smartEditService.isLaunchedInSmartEdit()) {
      return false
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From 3.2, the `SmartEditModule` is deprecated. You can either import the deprecated `SmartEditModule` (from core) in your app, or use the `SmartEditService` from `@spartacus/smartedit` lib.